# Induced torus action on tautological bundle on $\mathbb{P}^m$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^m}(1)$ be the tautological bundle on $\mathbb{P}^m$ and let $T := (\mathbb{C}^\times)^{m+1}$ act on $\mathbb{P}^m$ diagonally, i.e.,
$$
(t_0,\ldots,t_m) \cdot [x_0:\cdots:x_m] := [t_0x_0:\cdots:t_mx_m].
$$

The total space of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^m}(-1)$ is given by $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{P}^m$.
What is the induced action on the total space of the tautological bundle?

My guess: the action is trivial on $\mathbb{C}$ and the same on $\mathbb{P}^m$.

Furthermore, what is the action on the (other) line bundles $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^m} (k)$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The total space is not at all what you write.

Comment: Sorry, it should be the total space of $\mathcal{O}(-1)$. I fixed the typo.

Comment: I think you have a few misconceptions here. The total space of the trivial bundle is a product C times P^m. The tautological bundle’s (even the dual bundle’s) total space is not that product because it’s not trivial!